# Como evitar aque a pagina carregue quando eu clicar em Calcular no formulario com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou fazendo esse programa para um trabalho da faculdade com HTML CSS e JS.
Mas sempre que clico em calcular a pagina recarrega e o resultado consequentemente somo.
já procurei em outras perguntas aqui e em outros forums mas não encontrei nada que funcionasse 
se puderem ma ajudar, ficarei muito grato.

```js
/* Criado por João Divino em 20 de fevereiro de 2018 */

function calcular_media(){

    var sit="";
    var nota1;
    nota1 = document.media.nota1.value;
    var nota2;
    nota2 = document.media.nota1.value;
    var nota3;
    nota3 = document.media.nota1.value;
    var nota4;
    nota4 = document.media.nota1.value;

    var media = (4/(nota1+nota2+nota3+nota4));

    if (media >= 5) {
        if (media < 5 && media < 7) {
            sit = "Você esta de recuperação"
        } else {
            sit = "Você esta aprovado"
        }
    } else {
        sit = "Você foi reprovado";
    }
    document.getElementById("med").value=media;
    document.getElementById("sit").value=sit;
}
```

```css
.pgmedia {
    width: 100%;
}
.media input {
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.media textarea {
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.botaoCalcular {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 1px;
}
.media input {
    padding-left: 20px;
    color: #292929;
    font-size: 18px;
    background-color: #E9E9E9;
    border: 1px solid #E9E9E9;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.media textarea {
    padding-left: 20px;
    color: #292929;
    font-size: 18px;
    background-color: #E9E9E9;
    border: 1px solid #E9E9E9;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.botaoCalcular {
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 2px 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: 18px;
    opacity: 0.9;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #B22222;
    display: inline-block;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #500707;
    border-right: 1px solid #500707;
    position: center;
}
.botaoCalcular:hover {
    opacity: 1.0;
    transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title> Media Escolar</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Site para calcular média escolar">
    <meta name="Keywords" content="javascript, HTML, CSS, Ecma script, aprendizado, exercicios, Ti, desenvolvimento web,atividades, IMC, Calculdor, Calculador de Média escolaar">
    <meta name="robots" content="index, fallow">
    <meta name="author" content="João Divino da Silva">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/media_escolar.css">
    <script rel="scriptv" src="js/media_escolar.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="pgmedia">
    <form name ="media" class="media" tabindex="1" action="#" method="post">
        <input id="nota1" name="nota1" required="" type="text" placeholder="Sua Nota no 1° Bimestre" >
        <input id="nota2" name="nota2" required="" type="text" placeholder="Sua Nota no 2° Bimestre" >
        <input id="nota3" name="nota3" required="" type="text" placeholder="Sua Nota no 3° Bimestre" >
        <input id="nota4" name="nota4" required="" type="text" placeholder="Sua Nota no 4° Bimestre" >
        <button class="botaoCalcular"  onclick="calcular_media()">Calcular</button>
        <input id="med" name="media" type="text" placeholder="Sua média" readonly/>
        <label></label><textarea id="sit" name="situação" placeholder="Sua Situação" readonly></textarea>
    </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Olá João! Minha resposta não ajudou? Vi que a desmarcou. Não há problema nenhum em desmarcá-la, mas se puder dizer o motivo assim eu posso melhorar. ObG!

Comment: Perdão a intenção era marcar kkkk sou novo na plataforma, ja marquei novamente.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Só lembrando que seu código possui 3 problemas:
>
> **1.** Você está somando os valores de forma errada. É preciso converter os valores dos campos em números antes de somar, senão eles
> serão apenas concatenados.
>
> **2.** A divisão para pegar a média está errada: some os números e divida por 4, e não dividir 4 pela soma dos números.
>
> **3.** Esse `if` nunca vai ser verdadeiro: `if (media < 5 && media < 7) {`

**Veja no final da resposta o código otimizado e corrigido.**

---

Coloque no final da função:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

Isso irá impedir que o formulário seja submetido, evitando recarregamento da página.

Como dito também pelo Valdeir Psr, se definir o `type` do `button` como `type="button"`, o `event.preventDefault();` já não é necessário, mas também o `required` não terá efeito.

Mas eu vou um pouco além: se quer apenas fazer cálculos, não precisa nem usar `<form>` (*veja edit no final da resposta*). Use o `document.getElementById`:

```
function calcular_media(){

    var sit="";
    var nota1;
    nota1 = document.getElementById("nota1").value;
    var nota2;
    nota2 = document.getElementById("nota2").value;
    var nota3;
    nota3 = document.getElementById("nota3").value;
    var nota4;
    nota4 = document.getElementById("nota4").value;

    ...

}
```

**Código otimizado e corrigido:**

```js
function calcular_media(){

    var sit,
    nota1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("nota1").value),
    nota2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("nota2").value),
    nota3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("nota3").value),
    nota4 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("nota4").value),
    media = (nota1+nota2+nota3+nota4)/4;

   if (media >= 5 && media < 7) {
      sit = "Você esta de recuperação"
   } else if(media >= 7) {
            sit = "Você esta aprovado"
    } else {
        sit = "Você foi reprovado";
    }
    document.getElementById("med").value=media;
    document.getElementById("sit").value=sit;
    
    if(media){
       event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="pgmedia">
  <form class="media" tabindex="1">
     <input id="nota1" required type="text" placeholder="Sua Nota no 1° Bimestre" >
     <input id="nota2" required type="text" placeholder="Sua Nota no 2° Bimestre" >
     <input id="nota3" required type="text" placeholder="Sua Nota no 3° Bimestre" >
     <input id="nota4" required type="text" placeholder="Sua Nota no 4° Bimestre" >
     <button class="botaoCalcular"  onclick="calcular_media()">Calcular</button>
     <input id="med" type="text" name="media" placeholder="Sua média" readonly/>
     <label></label><textarea id="sit" name="situação" placeholder="Sua Situação" readonly></textarea>
  </form>
</div>
```

### Edit

Percebi você quer usar o `required` para um simples controle de campo vazio. Neste caso, você pode usar o `<form>`. O código corrigido acima foi alterado para usar com `<form>`.

Answer (score 1):

Isso acontece pois você não está definindo o atributo `type` no botão `<button class="botaoCalcular"  onclick="calcular_media()">Calcular</button>`.

Isso faz com que o navegador, automaticamente, atribua o valor desse atributo para `submit`, que é o envio de formulário.

Para evitar esse problema, basta adicionar o atributo `type="button"`. Ex:

```
<button type="button" class="botaoCalcular"  onclick="calcular_media()">Calcular</button>
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
/* Criado por João Divino em 20 de fevereiro de 2018 */

function calcular_media(){

    var sit="";
    var nota1;
    nota1 = document.media.nota1.value;
    var nota2;
    nota2 = document.media.nota1.value;
    var nota3;
    nota3 = document.media.nota1.value;
    var nota4;
    nota4 = document.media.nota1.value;

    var media = (4/(nota1+nota2+nota3+nota4));

    if (media >= 5) {
        if (media < 5 && media < 7) {
            sit = "Você esta de recuperação"
        } else {
            sit = "Você esta aprovado"
        }
    } else {
        sit = "Você foi reprovado";
    }
    document.getElementById("med").value=media;
    document.getElementById("sit").value=sit;
}
```

```css
.pgmedia {
    width: 100%;
}
.media input {
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.media textarea {
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.botaoCalcular {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 1px;
}
.media input {
    padding-left: 20px;
    color: #292929;
    font-size: 18px;
    background-color: #E9E9E9;
    border: 1px solid #E9E9E9;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.media textarea {
    padding-left: 20px;
    color: #292929;
    font-size: 18px;
    background-color: #E9E9E9;
    border: 1px solid #E9E9E9;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.botaoCalcular {
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 2px 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: 18px;
    opacity: 0.9;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #B22222;
    display: inline-block;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #500707;
    border-right: 1px solid #500707;
    position: center;
}
.botaoCalcular:hover {
    opacity: 1.0;
    transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title> Media Escolar</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Site para calcular média escolar">
    <meta name="Keywords" content="javascript, HTML, CSS, Ecma script, aprendizado, exercicios, Ti, desenvolvimento web,atividades, IMC, Calculdor, Calculador de Média escolaar">
    <meta name="robots" content="index, fallow">
    <meta name="author" content="João Divino da Silva">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/media_escolar.css">
    <script rel="scriptv" src="js/media_escolar.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="pgmedia">
    <form name ="media" class="media" tabindex="1" action="#" method="post">
        <input id="nota1" name="nota1" required="" type="text" placeholder="Sua Nota no 1° Bimestre" >
        <input id="nota2" name="nota2" required="" type="text" placeholder="Sua Nota no 2° Bimestre" >
        <input id="nota3" name="nota3" required="" type="text" placeholder="Sua Nota no 3° Bimestre" >
        <input id="nota4" name="nota4" required="" type="text" placeholder="Sua Nota no 4° Bimestre" >
        
        <button type="button" class="botaoCalcular"  onclick="calcular_media()">Calcular</button>
        
        <input id="med" name="media" type="text" placeholder="Sua média" readonly/>
        <label></label><textarea id="sit" name="situação" placeholder="Sua Situação" readonly></textarea>
    </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado pela resposta.
Foi uma verdadeira aula.
Obrigado de verdade ajudou muito.

Answer (score -3):

function calcular_media(){

```
    var sit="";
    var nota1;
    nota1 = document.media.nota1.value;
    var nota2;
    nota2 = document.media.nota1.value;
    var nota3;
    nota3 = document.media.nota1.value;
    var nota4;
    nota4 = document.media.nota1.value;

    var media = ((nota1+nota2+nota3+nota4)/4);

    if (media >= 5) {
        if (media < 5 && media < 7) {
            sit = "Você esta de recuperação"
        } else {
            sit = "Você esta aprovado"
        }
    } else {
        sit = "Você foi reprovado";
    }
    document.getElementById("med").value=media;
    document.getElementById("sit").value=sit;
}
```

```css
.pgmedia {
    width: 100%;
}
.media input {
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.media textarea {
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.botaoCalcular {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 1px;
}
.media input {
    padding-left: 20px;
    color: #292929;
    font-size: 18px;
    background-color: #E9E9E9;
    border: 1px solid #E9E9E9;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.media textarea {
    padding-left: 20px;
    color: #292929;
    font-size: 18px;
    background-color: #E9E9E9;
    border: 1px solid #E9E9E9;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.botaoCalcular {
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 2px 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: 18px;
    opacity: 0.9;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #B22222;
    display: inline-block;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #500707;
    border-right: 1px solid #500707;
    position: center;
}
.botaoCalcular:hover {
    opacity: 1.0;
    transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title> Media Escolar</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Site para calcular média escolar">
    <meta name="Keywords" content="javascript, HTML, CSS, Ecma script, aprendizado, exercicios, Ti, desenvolvimento web,atividades, IMC, Calculdor, Calculador de Média escolaar">
    <meta name="robots" content="index, fallow">
    <meta name="author" content="João Divino da Silva">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/media_escolar.css">
    <script rel="scriptv" src="js/media_escolar.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="pgmedia">
    <form name ="media" class="media" tabindex="1" action="#" method="post">
        <input id="nota1" name="nota1" required="" type="text" placeholder="Sua Nota no 1° Bimestre" >
        <input id="nota2" name="nota2" required="" type="text" placeholder="Sua Nota no 2° Bimestre" >
        <input id="nota3" name="nota3" required="" type="text" placeholder="Sua Nota no 3° Bimestre" >
        <input id="nota4" name="nota4" required="" type="text" placeholder="Sua Nota no 4° Bimestre" >
        <button class="botaoCalcular"  onclick="calcular_media()">Calcular</button>
        <input id="med" name="media" type="text" placeholder="Sua média" readonly/>
        <label></label><textarea id="sit" name="situação" placeholder="Sua Situação" readonly></textarea>
    </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```